# How to debug the script in Visual Studio after I click the publish button?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

I am using [scott hanselman's example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx) to publish an asp.net web application to docker container.

There is a PowerShell script inside the project generated by the extention automatically but I don't understand it well. So I want to set breakpoints to debug it. I believe the script is executing after I right click publish button. The script has 350 lines so I don't want to post all of them just a function here.

```
            #Requires –Version 3.0

        <#
        .DESCRIPTION
            Publish an application to Docker container
            Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=529706 to learn more about the scirpt

        .EXAMPLE
            & '.\contoso-Docker-publish.ps1' -packOutput $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp -pubxmlFile '.\contoso-Docker.pubxml'

        .EXAMPLE
            $publishProperties = @{ "SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish"="http://contoso.cloudapp.net/Home"; }
            & '.\contoso-Docker-publish.ps1' $publishProperties $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp '.\contoso-Docker.pubxml'
        #>

        [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
        param($publishProperties, $packOutput, $pubxmlFile)

        <#
            Core publish functions
        #>

        function Publish-AspNetDocker {
            [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
            param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
                [AllowNull()]
                $publishProperties,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
                $packOutput,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
                $pubxmlFile
            )
            process {

                # Merge publish properties from $publishProperties and $pubxmlFile. The value from $publishProperties will be taken if conflict.
                if ($pubxmlFile -and (Test-Path $pubxmlFile)) {
                    if(!$publishProperties) {
                        $publishProperties = @{}
                    }
                    ([xml](Get-Content $pubxmlFile)).SelectNodes(("/*/*/*")) | % { 
                        if (!$publishProperties.ContainsKey($_.Name)) { $publishProperties.Add($_.Name, $_.InnerText) } 
                    }
                }

                if (!$publishProperties) {
                    throw 'publishProperties is empty and pubxmlFile is not valid, cannot publish'
                }

                # Trim the trailing '\' to avoid quoting issue
                $packOutput = $packOutput.TrimEnd('\')
                $profileName = (Split-Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf).Replace('-publish.ps1', '')

                # Search for current publish profile and publish script in the package output directory
                $profile = Get-ChildItem -Path $packOutput -Filter "$profileName.pubxml" -Recurse | Where { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.Directory.FullName "$profileName-publish.ps1") } | Select -First 1
                if (!$profile) {
                    throw 'cannot find current publish profile {0}.pubxml in the package output location {1}' -f $profileName, $packOutput
                }
                $dockerfileBasePath = $profile.DirectoryName

                # Find the correct Dockerfile
                $dockerfileRelPath = $publishProperties["DockerfileRelativePath"]
                $dockerfilePath = (Resolve-Path (Join-Path $dockerfileBasePath $dockerfileRelPath)).Path

                # Work around a Docker build command bug docker issue #13898
                $dockerfilePath = '{0}{1}' -f $packOutput, $dockerfilePath.Substring($packOutput.Length)

                # Publish the application to a Docker container
                Publish-DockerContainerApp $publishProperties $packOutput $dockerfilePath
            }
        }
```

However it didn't stop at the breakpoints at all. So how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do that. Adding a PowerShell project to Visual Studio, you have to use PowerShell tools for VS. Right clicking the project and setting the arguments.